# Не могу записать в состояние значение перед рендерингом React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Хочу из **props** match получить название страницы, вот ниже попытка при запуске реакта, при этом в консоле не показывает this.props.match.path

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Post from './Post'

export default class Posts extends Component {
    state = {
      namePage: ''
   };
   componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({
        namePage: this.props.match.path.slice(1)[0].toUpperCase() + this.props.match.path.slice(2)
    })
  render(){
    return (
             <div>
                   <h2>{this.state.namePage}</h2>
             </div>

    )
}

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вот что получаю при запуске реакта, помогите понять что я делаю не так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно подключить компоненты к react-router-dom

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Post from './Post';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Route path="/post" component={Post} />
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

По умолчанию в props компонента match не передаётся

Comment: У меня подключен реакт роутер дом.<Route exact path="/" component={Posts} />  дело в том что у меня Posts это стартовая страница приложения, может match.path получает значение только во время перехода на компонент?

Comment: match.path возвращает всё кроме домена, применив к строке "/".slice(1)[0] получаем undefined, т.к. слеш обрезали и выбрали первый символ пустой строки, а затем пытаемся применить к undefined метод toUpperCase() и получаем ошибку.